# Serving Static file publically in nodejs :- Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, static, backend

In my nodejs server file, I am trying to server static folder the code goes as below :-

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { connectDB } = require("./config/connectDB");
connectDB();
const upload = require("./routes/uploadsFile");
const user = require("./routes/user");
const path = require("path");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json("content-type", "application/json"));

const publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../uploads");
console.log(publicFolder);
app.use(express.static(publicFolder));

app.use("/api/v1/upload", upload);
app.use("/api/v1/user", user);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started Listening On PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

The folder structures goes below :-

[image: This is the ss of my folder structure]

The same error I am getting as everyone

> Cannot GET /uploads/image/actual-size/banner-Image-1.jpg

***Can someone please help me. I have gone through many problem already answered like this on Stackoverflow, but unable to get the proper solution.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `uploads` to be the root directory for serving static files which means the request paths must not start with `/uploads`. In your example above change the path to:

`/image/actual-size/banner-Image-1.jpg`

From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
> name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

Comment: Thanks man, I also got the solution while I was answering my own question, before you. Thanks again for the help though. Really appreciate that.

Comment: Happy to help, if you like you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Why not. I did. Thanks Mann.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of the problem.

I was calling the GET URL by

```
localhost:${port}/uploads/image/actual-size/image.jpg
```

But I had to call like this because uploads folder is being server by default

```
localhost:${port}/image/actual-size/image.jpg
```